# Update Connection Profile: The Current Identity has not been Registered

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm able to run the hyperledger fabric network successfully. Now, I want to add new and organisation at run time. I have made all the changes and able to setup new peer and organisation. But to deploy BNA on peers, I update the **connection profile** JSON file and add the information of the newly added Peer and Organisation. After updating the connection profiles, I create the new cards using these updated JSON files.

But when I try to execute any command using these cards I get the identity not registered error. For example if I run the following command:

```
composer network ping -c abc@network
```

I get the following error:

> Error: Error trying to ping. Error: transaction returned with failure:
>   Error: The current identity, with the name 'admin' and the identifier
>   '76216ac98acbafbae9263a7963866ce535158cdfde6fb1607f180c7846a7bc45',
>   has not been registered

And when I try to run composer playground and connect using these cards, I get the following error:

> An error has occurred Error: Error trying to ping. SyntaxError:
>   Unexpected end of JSON input

And this is what composer playground logs say:

> ERROR   :ConnectorServer          :connectionPing()
>   {"message":"Error trying to ping. SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON
>   input","stack":"Error: Error trying to ping. SyntaxError: Unexpected
>   end of JSON input\n    at _checkRuntimeVersions.then.catch
>   (/Users/BAY/.nvm/versions/node/v8.15.0/lib/node_modules/composer-playground/node_modules/composer-connector-hlfv1/lib/hlfconnection.js:842:34)